# kdb: how does the vs keyword work for 24 60 60 vs 3805

Tags: kdb

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vs/#byte-representation

Based on above, I know that this converts 50 into base 2 representation.

```
q)2 vs 50
1 1 0 0 1 0
```

But how do I interpret the 2 results below?

```
q)24 60 60 vs 3805
1 3 25

q)100 8 3 6 4 vs 100000
73 4 2 4 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you took `3805` as a number of seconds then `24 60 60` will split it out into
`hours` `minutes` `seconds`

```
q)24 60 60 vs 3805
1 3 25
q)0D00:00:01*3805
0D01:03:25.000000000
```

Doing this calculation more explicitly in `q` may look something like:

```
q){reverse floor %[;1^ prev l]y mod l:prds reverse x}[24 60 60;3805]
1 3 25
```